# WEBBrowser Control; Is it possible to save the Webbrowser Content to a SQL DB?

Tags: c#, controls, browser

Can the content of a webbrowser control in C# winforms be serialized for saving to a sql server db for retrieval and display? Would that be the route for saving and retrieving html content to and from a db?

Answer (score 1):

Use the property WebBrowser.DocumentElement.innerhtml to get and set the webrowsers html. You could also save the html to a .htm file instead of the database and use the webrowser.navigate2 method. sometimes storing blobs in a database is a bad idea (performance).